# Data dashboard for SQL server database

Tags: visualization, sql

I am working on developing a data dashboard / app for a Microsoft SQL database. Currently, I am developing the dashboard using Shiny and R. The app is mostly for exploratory analysis to allow people to filter out some subset of data, build some plots, and export data / plots.

My question is what are some other options for creating this type of dashboard? I am aware of Tableau.

Comment: http://periscopedata.com

Comment: Please mark as answer if appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider PowerBI. It offers a couple of useful licensing scenarios (bundled with Office 365 etc.) and also has connectors to source data that already works well with SQL Server.

You did not say if SQL Server is running on premises or in the cloud, but PowerBI should work in both cases.

Comment: +1 for Power BI. It is free for basic desktop usage and the R integration is great compared to Tableau.

Comment: Agreed, thanks for adding the R benefits. This is also substantial value as part of the visualization pack.